# Problem with sending events to analytics over Facebook SDK

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-analytics

I using com.facebook.android:facebook-core:5.0.0
When I try send event to analytics like this

```
val logger = AppEventsLogger.newLogger(context, "my_app_id")  
logger.logEvent("event", Bundle())
```

But I has error in logs

```
    E/GraphResponse: {HttpStatus: 404, errorCode: 803, subErrorCode: -1,  
 errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: (#803) Some of the aliases you  
 requested do not exist: "my_app_id"}
```

App was setup like in https://developers.facebook.com/quickstarts/?platform=android

Facebook's support don't answer

Comment: so....did you actually use your app id, or did you try with the string "my_app_id"?

Comment: @luschn I actually use my app id :D thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fix with two point:

1: add two activities in manifest .

```
<activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
          android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
          android:label="@string/app_name"/>

<activity android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
          android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

2: replace `manifestPlaceholders` in app/build.gradle with

```
resValue "string", "facebook_app_id", "$fbAppId"  
resValue "string", "fb_login_protocol_scheme", "fb$fbAppId"
```

I don't know why did't work manifestPlaceholders.